# Custom "Maximum Value" Function Ignoring String

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In `Column A`, I have a set of numbers in a format where:

> K = Thousand (10^3)
> M = Million (10^6)
> B = Billion (10^9)
> ...
> N = Nonillion (10^30)
> d = decillion (10^33)

And I would like to be able to find the **maximum parsed value's index** from this column.

I had already written a custom function in the Apps Script, so that I can parse these values into scientific notation, when I need to perform math with them:

```js
/**
 * Parses scientific notation from short notation.
 * 
 * @pararm {number} input The value to parse.
 * @return The parsed number in scientific notation.
 * @customfunction
 */
function parse(input) {
  return String(input).replace('K', 'E+3').replace('M', 'E+6').replace('B', 'E+9').replace('T', 'E+12').replace('q', 'E+15').replace('Q', 'E+18').replace('s', 'E+21').replace('S', 'E+24').replace('o', 'E+27').replace('N', 'E+30').replace('d', 'E+33');
}
```

Ex: `=parse("10B")` would yield `10E+9`.

I then took this, and attempted to make a function that will get the maximum value's index:

```js
/**
 * Discern the maximum value contained in a column, and return its index 
 * 
 * @param {string} column The column letter to check
 * @param {number} start The first index (row) to check
 * @param {number} end The last index (row) to check
 * @customfunction
 */
function customMax(column, start, end){

  var max = 0;
  var maxIndex = 0;

  for(var i = start; i<= end;i++){

    var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(column + String(i)).getValue();
    var parsedVal = parseInt(parse(value));

    if(parsedVal > max){
      max = parsedVal;
      maxIndex = i;
    }
  }

  return maxIndex;
}
```

This code makes sense to me, and looks like it should work, however:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 300T |
| 2 | 1d |

With data such as this, `1d` is much larger than `300T`, however running `=customMax("A", "1", "2")` yields `1`.

The only consistency that I have found is that the Apps Script seems to be ignoring the `T`, `d`, or any other following character, and solely going off of the base of the number.

Comment: @Tanaike No apology required - the inputs are A1, and A2, in that order, and the expected output is that index `2` should be the largest, as `1d` is equivalent to `1E+33`, whereas `300T` is only `300E+12`.

Comment: Use `Number` instead of `parseInt`

Comment: @idfurw This seems to fix OP's issue, perhaps you can post this as a **good answer** on this question.

Comment: I'd definitely accept just that as an answer. Although I'd also appreciate some insight as to why the `Number()` constructor works, and `parseInt()` does not.

Comment: @David You can also check this online resource: [Number() vs parseInt()](https://thisthat.dev/number-constructor-vs-parse-int/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Number` instead of `parseInt` for scientific notation

As described in the [example of parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#using_parseint),

string of a scientific notation would be omitted and not interpreted

Reference:

- [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)
- [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [Number() vs parseInt()](https://thisthat.dev/number-constructor-vs-parse-int/) (share by [@SputnikDrunk2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15384825/sputnikdrunk2))